# Redeclaring pure virtual function

Tags: c++

I recently came across code of the following kind:

```
struct A {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct B : public A {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct C : public B {
    virtual void foo() override {
    }
};
```

Is there any purpose in redeclaring a pure virtual method?

Even more importantly: Does this change semantics? I.e is `B::foo` shadowing `A::foo` and introducing a new vftable?

Whats happens in the above example if `A::foo` is actually not pure virtual but provides an implementation (still compiles for me)?

Comment: Even if `A::foo()` is not pure virtual, `virtual void foo() = 0;` in `struct B` makes `struct B` abstract, i.e. it may not be instanced. [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ed3a18d56ef8c13) The sense of repeating the pure virtual in `B` (as it is currently in the exposed code) might be for documentation. Even although it is not really necessary it doesn't cause any harm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pure virtual methods in derived abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603579/pure-virtual-methods-in-derived-abstract-class)

Comment: It doesn't change a thing, but I'd skip `virtual` in the subclasses and put `override` on both of them. You may even make `A::foo` a pure virtual _and_ have a default implementation. That's quite common for base class destructors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the example from  [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class):

> ```
> struct Abstract {
>     virtual void f() = 0; // pure virtual
> }; // "Abstract" is abstract
>  
> struct Concrete : Abstract {
>     void f() override {} // non-pure virtual
>     virtual void g();     // non-pure virtual
> }; // "Concrete" is non-abstract
>  
> struct Abstract2 : Concrete {
>     void g() override = 0; // pure virtual overrider
> }; // "Abstract2" is abstract
>  
> int main()
> {
>     // Abstract a; // Error: abstract class
>     Concrete b; // OK
>     Abstract& a = b; // OK to reference abstract base
>     a.f(); // virtual dispatch to Concrete::f()
>     // Abstract2 a2; // Error: abstract class (final overrider of g() is pure)
> }
> ```

> Is there any purpose in redeclaring a pure virtual method?

There is a purpose in declaring a virtual method as pure in a derived class: `Abstract2` can decalre `g` to be pure virtual even if it is not pure in `Concrete`.

> Does this change semantics? I.e is B::foo shadowing A::foo and introducing a new
> vftable?

No.

> Whats happens in the above example if A::foo is actually not pure virtual but provides an implementation (still compiles for me)?

See the example.

You do not have to delcare a method as `virtual` in a derived class. When it is declared `virtual` in the base it is also `virtual` in derived classes. In a nutshell, the `=0` just tells the compiler that there is not necessarily a definition and that the class is abstract. Your example is the same as:

```
struct AA {                       // abstract
    virtual void foo() = 0;         
};

struct BB : public AA { };         // abstract

struct CC : public BB {            // concrete
    void foo() override {}
};
```

The only difference I am aware of is the type of `BB::foo`:

```
// above
std::cout << std::is_same< decltype(&BB::foo), void (AA::*)()>::value;
std::cout << std::is_same< decltype(&BB::foo), void (BB::*)()>::value;
std::cout << std::is_same< decltype(&BB::foo), void (CC::*)()>::value << "\n";
// your example
std::cout << std::is_same< decltype(&B::foo), void (A::*)()>::value;
std::cout << std::is_same< decltype(&B::foo), void (B::*)()>::value;
std::cout << std::is_same< decltype(&B::foo), void (C::*)()>::value << "\n";
```

Output is:

```
100
010
```

That is, redeclaring `foo` in `B` introduces the name `foo` directly in `B`. `B::foo` is a member function of `B`. On the other hand in my example `BB::foo` is the method from `AA`. However, this doesn't affect `C::foo`.

Comment: To clarify: Redeclaring a non-pure function as pure will "get rid" of the original implementation provided by the parent but otherwise doesn't change a thing (except for guarateeing that the class will be abstract)?

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann not sure what you mean with "otherwise", what else should it affect?

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann in case you refer to a vtable.. Thats an implementation detail. Afaik the standard makes no mention of a vtable. Instead it specifies how virtual methods and overriding is supposed to work (and most/all compilers use a vtable to implementat that)

Comment: sure its an implementation detail, yet if I understood your answer correctly, `foo()` will always refer to the same virtual function (i.e `A::foo`), no matter whether it has been redeclared as pure in a subclass. So a call to it will always happen through the vftable of A (in any sane compiler). I think we're slightly talking past each other, but your comments helped clarifying the situation for me anyways. Thank you.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann wait a sec.. I just discovered that there is a difference ;) Will update the answer

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann "So a call to it will always happen through the vftable of A" how would you notice if that didn't happen? I don't really understand what you think could go wrong

Comment: I'm not concerned that anything can go wrong. I'm just curious as how this kind of code behaves. Good catch with the function pointers btw.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann it would behave the same also if there was no vtable. So strictly speaking the answer to "...will always happen through the vftable of A?" is No

Answer (score 0):

I found an example where redeclaring pure virtual method is required. Both gcc 10 and clang 11 requires the repeated declaration when the pure virtual method is used in the implementation of a descendant class itself abstract. Here is an example :

```
class Transition {
  public: 
  virtual int* apply(int*p, double*e) = 0;
  virtual long* apply(double*h, double*e) = 0;
  virtual long* apply(long* l, double *e) { return l;}
};

class MTransition : public Transition {
  public:
  //virtual int* apply(int*p, double*e) = 0; // duplicate from upper class but required
  virtual long* apply(double*h, double*e) {
    int a= *(Transition::apply((int*)h, e)); // not resolved correctly without the duplicate declaration
    return a?nullptr:nullptr;
  }
};

class TransitionTest : public MTransition {
  public: 
  virtual int* apply(int*p, double*e) { return p; }
};

int main() {
  TransitionTest t;
  double /*d1=1.0,*/ d2=2.0;
  int i1=1;
  /*int *pi = t.apply(&d1, &d2); */
  int *pi = t.apply(&i1, &d2);
  return pi?(*pi):0;
}
```

As such, this programs does not link. I get the following error:

```
clang++ -Wall yo.cpp 
yo.cpp:19:16: warning: 'TransitionTest::apply' hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]
  virtual int* apply(int*p, double*e) { return p; }
               ^
yo.cpp:11:17: note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'MTransition::apply' declared here: type mismatch at 1st parameter ('double *' vs 'int *')
  virtual long* apply(double*h, double*e) { 
                ^
1 warning generated.
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/yo-cb0979.o: in function `MTransition::apply(double*, double*)':
yo.cpp:(.text._ZN11MTransition5applyEPdS0_[_ZN11MTransition5applyEPdS0_]+0x27): undefined reference to `Transition::apply(int*, double*)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And it is worst if I try other call to `apply` in main (compilation error in this case, linked to the warning).

To make it works, I need to write the `MTransition` class like this:

```
class MTransition : public Transition {
  public:
  virtual int* apply(int*p, double*e) = 0; // duplicate from upper class but required
  virtual long* apply(double*h, double*e) {
    int a= *(apply((int*)h, e)); // not resolved correctly without the duplicate declaration
    return a?nullptr:nullptr;
  }
};
```

But I do not succeed into calling `t.apply(&d1, &d2);` in main. It seems to me that the definition of `apply(int*p, double*e)` in `TransitionTest` hides (as stated by the warning) the other `apply` that should have been inherited.

EDIT (again): I found the solution in [c++ overloaded virtual function warning by clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515183)
When overloading (or partially overwriting) a method in a derived class, one needs to use the `using Base::method` to keep the other overloaded methods.

It gives:

```
class Transition {
  public:
  virtual int* apply(int*p, double*e) = 0;
  virtual int* apply(double*h, double*e) = 0;
  virtual int* apply(long* l, double *e) { std::cerr << "Transition::apply(long*,double*)" << std::endl; return nullptr;}
};

class MTransition : public Transition {
  public:
  using Transition::apply;
  virtual int* apply(double*h, double*e) {
    std::cerr << "MTransition::apply(double*,double*)" << std::endl;
    int a= *(apply((int*)h, e)); // not resolved correctly without the duplicate declaration
    return a?nullptr:nullptr;
  }
};

class TransitionTest : public MTransition {
  public:
  using MTransition::apply;
  virtual int* apply(int*p, double*e) { std::cerr << "TransitionTest::apply(int*,double*)" << std::endl; return p; }
};

int main() {
  TransitionTest t;
  double d1=1.0, d2=2.0;
  //int i1=1;
  int *pi = t.apply(&d1, &d2);
  //int *pi = t.apply(&i1, &d2); 
  return pi?(*pi):0;
}
```

Comment: FYI - The redeclaration is necessary because apply(int*, double*) in the base class is private.  change it to protected, and reference it as Transition::apply() in MTransition and the duplicate is no longer required.  https://godbolt.org/z/bsWGK3jos

Comment: I updated my code. I still get an error (at link time now). See the edited post.